# jquery Fusion Charts - does anyone know how to make a Fusion chart with the tabs on the side?

Tags: jquery

Sorry I have no code but I haven't started building yet. If you can vision a 1000px x 200 px graph that has 2 tabs on the right side of the graph, that when you click each one a graph displays in the same area. So in div standards you can have one 1000px x 200px div and then to the direct right of that have a 20px x 100px on top of a 20px x 100px that are clickable to change the graph in the 1000px x 200px area.

Answer (score 0):

Using the jQuery [Tabs widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#entry-examples) you can style the list and divs so they display side-by-side.

I added some CSS to the stock example from the docs to achieve that

```
div#tabs > div {
    width: 80%;
}
div#tabs ul {
    float: right;
    width: 10%;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwu6v/1/)

You can then have whatever chart or other content you'd like in the div that the tabs select.